Android - Firebase realtime database not updating when app in background
I am trying to update firebase realtime database from FirebaseMessagingService but it never update when updating from FirebaseMessagingService.
So logic is when User A send Message to User B (app in background) it calls FirebaseMessagingService after saving message to local database i need to update message status to delivered so User A will get notify that his message has reached to User B. User B getting notifications and i can see in logs that User B log got executed before setting that value and its listener never get called for success or failure. I also cross checked database reference that is correct.
i tried with setValue and updateChildren method but failed to update data.I removed the listener for clean code.
1:
DatabaseReference messageRef = databaseReference.child(messageNodeKey);
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("Status", msgstatus);
messageRef.updateChildren(update);

2:
DatabaseReference messageRef = databaseReference.child(messageNodeKey).child("Status");
messageRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+snapshot+" "+snapshot.exists());
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            messageRef.setValue(msgstatus)   
        }
    }
}           

I can update the value when device is in foreground but not when it's calling from FirebaseMessagingService. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.
Update: After enable debugging and trying with setvalue
DatabaseReference messageRef = databaseReference.child(messageNodeKey).child("Status");
messageRef.setValue(msgstatus)

Log after enable firebase debugging
RepoOperation D  set: /Chat/xxx-aaa/messages/-O5eF3_t0HESRIzjS4HE/Status
DataOperation D  set: /Chat/xxx-aaa/messages/-O5eF3_t0HESRIzjS4HE/Status Delivered
RepoOperation D  Aborting transactions for path: /Chat/xxx-aaa/messages/-O5eF3_t0HESRIzjS4HE/Status. Affected: 
WM-WorkerWrapper I  Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=40fbeba3-c39c-49dc-8c09-deda65767395, tags={ com.elaxer.Settings_Fragmets.Notification_WorkManager, Notification } ]
System W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
LocalRequestInterceptor W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
2024-09-01 02:34:05.829 FirebaseAuth D  Notifying id token listeners about user ( xxx ).


(not the downvoter) Most likely Android closes the connection after a few minutes when the app is backgrounded. If you enable debug logging, you might be able to confirm that.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen All things happen in 3-4 seconds from getting notification till generating last log before database updating. Still i will set debug log for more information. I will update soon

Most likely Android closes the connection after a few minutes when the app is backgrounded. From the documentation:

On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

If you enable debug logging, you might be able to confirm that.
If that is indeed the cause, you can (detect this connection state and then) toggle the Firebase client offline and then online to get back to a connected state.

Please check updated code with the new logs of firebase

Rather than asking me to check your logs, does the first part of my answer make sense and could it explain what's happening on your app? If so, did the log output confirm that this is the case?

sorry but i really don't understand the exact meaning of log i got. I am still not sure why i am getting value updated thats why

Also i addOnCompleteListener and addOnFailureListener but none got called. I am not using AppCheckProvider which also showing in log.

If neither your onComplete nor onFailed is called, the client is usually not connected to the network - which would match with what I said in my answer.

goOnline works but it cause other issues like it also update last active time of user but i need to figure this out. The main issue is resolve by calling goOnline(); . Thanks a lot for your help.
